# How to remove duplicates without pandas?

Tags: python

This is the data

```
row1| sbkjd nsdnak ABC 
row2| vknfe edcmmi ABC
row3| fjnfn msmsle XYZ
row4| sdkmm tuiepd XYZ
row5| adjck rulsdl LMN
```

I have already tried this using `pandas` and got help from stackoverflow. But, I want to be able to remove the duplicates without having to use the `pandas` library or any library in general. So, only one of the rows having "ABC" must be chosen, only one of the rows having "XYZ" must be chosen and the last row is unique, so, it should be chosen. How do I do this?
So, my final output should contain this:

> [ row1 **or** row2 + row3 **or** row4 + row5 ]

Comment: what format is the data represented in?

Comment: Use the "ABC" and so on as keys of a dictionary.

Comment: How do you decide whether row 1 or row 2 should be chosen?

Comment: I want any of the 2 rows. It doesn't matter. I just want the duplicate one duplicate "ABC" row to be removed and one duplicate "XYZ" row to be removed

Answer (score 0):

This should only select the unique rows from your original table. If there are two or more rows which share duplicate data, it will select the first row.

```py
data = [["sbkjd", "nsdnak", "ABC"],
        ["vknfe", "edcmmi", "ABC"],
        ["fjnfn", "msmsle", "XYZ"],
        ["sdkmm", "tuiepd", "XYZ"],
        ["adjck", "rulsdl", "LMN"]]

def check_list_uniqueness(candidate_row, unique_rows):
    for element in candidate_row:
        for unique_row in unique_rows:
            if element in unique_row:
                return False
    return True

final_rows = []
for row in data:
    if check_list_uniqueness(row, final_rows):
        final_rows.append(row)

print(final_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Bash command would do (assuming your data is in a file called `test`, and that values of column 4 do not appear in other columns)

```
cut -d ' ' -f 4 test | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[ ]\)\1/\1/g' | tr ' ' '\n' | while read str; do grep -m 1 $str test; done
```

`cut -d ' ' -f 4 test` chooses the data in the fourth column
`tr '\n' ' '` turns the column into a row (translating new line character to a space)
`sed 's/\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[ ]\)\1/\1/g'` deletes the repetitions
`tr ' ' '\n'` turns the row of unique values to a column
`while read str; do grep -m 1 $str test; done` reads the unique words and prints the first line from `test` that matches that word